# Are trojan's a concern when manually modifying objects from matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently discovered that by using `dir()` on an object made with `matplotlib`, one can get direct access to different attributes of an object.

***For example:*** You have a scatter plot called `scat`, you can access it's attributes using `print(dir(scat))`. Within the printed list one can find `'ax'`. And in fact, one can access scat's axes by using `scat.ax`. Furthermore, you can change some of these attributes. For instance, with `scat`, you can make the axes invisible by running `scat.ax._visible = False`.

After using these things on a project that required constant modifications of the plots and widgets, *I was told that setting these variables manually, as shown above, could expose my computer to hidden Trojans.* Furthermore, I couldn't find much reading material on this specific way of modifying matplotlib objects.

So, even if it is probably bad practice to not use the `set` methods that come with matplotlib, I still want to be aware of the risks.

How concerned should I be about using this in the future for better plots?

Comment: I doubt it exposes you to Trojans.  But using private methods and attribute exposes you to having code that doesn’t run on the next version of matplotlib because the private attribute changes or goes away

Comment: The advice you received makes no sense (or at least, the version of the advice that you've relayed to us makes no sense. It's possible the original advice made more sense).